# Is it possible to set default value for asp:Label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, default-value

I have more labels in `TemplateField` that are inside `GridView`. For example, this Label shows for every record in database:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%#: Item.Name %>'></asp:Label>
```

But sometimes, column Name doesn't have value and I want to show `-` instead of `String.Empty`.

I could write some function for it, but there are many columns and I would rather solve this in one place if possible. So I'm asking is it somehow possible to change/override/set default values for `asp:Label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can do it using condition:

```
<%#: !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Name)?Item.Name:"-" %>
```

Or you can also inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label class and create your own control and then use it.

```
[Bindable(true), DefaultValue("-"), Localizable(true), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty), WebCategory("Appearance"), WebSysDescription("Label_Text")]
        public virtual string Text
```

Text property is public and virtual, you car easily override it.

Comment: Yes this is what i ment by function, but i wonder if there is a way to override default value of `asp:Label` that is `String.Empty` by default.